# How to separate while loops?

Tags: c++

I tried to make a loop within the range of 3 numbers, but then on my 2nd statement it would already have updated the first variable due to the 1st while statement. Is there a way to separate the two statements so that it would take the digit of the inputted number instead of the updated one?

```
cin >> num1 >> num2 >> num3;

while(num1 <= num2) {    
        cout << num1 << " ";
        num1++;
}
cout << endl;

while(num1 <= num3) {
    if(num1%2 != 0) {
        cout << num1 << " ";
    }
    num1++;
}
```

Comment: You need and array and a loop!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Save it in a *temporary*:

```
cin >> num1 >> num2 >> num3;

const auto t0 = num1;

while(num1 <= num2){
    
        cout << num1 << " ";
        num1++;
}
    cout << endl;

num1 = t0;

while(num1 <= num3){
    if(num1%2 != 0){
        cout << num1 << " ";
    }
    num1++;
}
```